# How I can create this table

Tags: tables

I have this:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{c|c}
pos 1 & pos 2  \\
\hline
pos 1 & pos 2  \\
\end{tabular}
```

When I writte into the table a lot of text, the text go out of the page
But I want get this:
[image]

How can I introduce text without break the table and the checks??

Thank you

Best regards

Comment: What is the main concern in creating such a table? Is it the text or the headers?

Comment: My main problem is introduce the text. Thanks

Comment: Do you want san serif fonts? Do you want the crayon-like checkmark and x? Do you want the vertical line to be broken in two places? Do you really want the horizontal lines? Do you really want the vertical one?

Comment: just look like the photo. I`m beta of latex. Or something I can see an example

Comment: Do note how Werner was able to add only four lines to your example to get something that would show the problem you were talking about.  For future questions, if you can create a document that shows your problem, it's much easier for everyone to understand what you want.  Benjamin McKay gave five options for what you could have meant by "I want this", and it turned out he was incorrect on all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `p`aragraph-like content in `tabular` columns using a `p{<len>}`-column:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ p{17em} | p{150pt} }
  pos 1 & pos 2 \\
  \hline
  \lipsum*[1] & \lipsum*[2]
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

`<len>` can be any TeX length.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried to reproduce the figure shown by the user who has asked the question adding the check marks using `pifont`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum,pifont}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{7cm}|p{7cm}}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\Large \color{Green}{\ding{51}}} Hello } & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{{\Large \color{Orange}{\ding{55}}} Hello}\\ \hline
\lipsum[1]&  \lipsum[2]     \\ \hline
other text    &   other text \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```